# How to do Changes to Edit text field which is in the main activity, from the activity loaded inside the tab host which is in the main activity?

Tags: android, activerecord, tabs, android-tabhost

I am developing an app, where in my main activity, there is a tab host and a edit text field. Tab host will load different activities inside each tab when changing tabs. In each activity that loads in each tab I have placed  a button. When I click the button I need some text to be displayed in the Edit text in the main activity.But I am getting "app forced closed" whenever i try to initialize the edit text field in the other activities than the main activity.

So if anybody can help me get the edit text get value from the press from the button in the activity loaded in the tab it would be a great help

This is the screen shot
blue box will be the activity that loads in every tab, out of it will be the main activity

[image: Screen shot of my app]

This is what Logcat out put looks like when the force close occurs.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.batz.voiceforyou/com.batz.voiceforyou.Things}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2065)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1906)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:553)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4129)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17143)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at com.batz.voiceforyou.Things.onCreate(Things.java:19)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5013)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
03-24 17:55:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23581):    ... 18 more
```

Here is the MainActivity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

String text="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    final EditText mainText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.maintext);


    Resources res =  getResources();
    TabHost tabs =  getTabHost();

    Intent regular =  new Intent(this, Regular.class);
    TabSpec reg =  tabs.newTabSpec("Regular")
            .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContent(regular);

    Intent things =  new Intent(this, Things.class);
    TabSpec thngs =  tabs.newTabSpec("Things")
            .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContent(things);

    tabs.addTab(reg);
    tabs.addTab(thngs);

    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

}


}
```

This is one of the activity that loads inside the tab

```
public class Regular extends Activity {
String text="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.regular);


    //final EditText mainText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.maintext);
    //text=mainText.getText().toString();

    Button regbtn =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.regularbutton);
    regbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            text=text+" regular";
            //mainText.setText(text);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Here you can see the 3 line which I have commented,
If I remove those lines the app will force close when starting.
If you want I can share the layouts too

Comment: we need to look at your code, post Things.java

Comment: Ok I have added the codes, if you want I can add the layout xml too

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to change the view of one class in another, you can create a copy of view by inflating it, but it doesn't change, so I will suggest you to use Fragments instead of TabHost

Comment: ah ok ill do a research on it and see thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with your existing setup by sending a broadcast.

**First**, create a BroadcastReceiver in your MainActivity like this:

```
public static final String ACTION_UPDATE_TEXT = "com.batz.voiceforyou.UPDATE_TEXT";
public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "text";

private BroadcastReceiver textReceiver = new  BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && ACTION_UPDATE_TEXT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String text = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TEXT);
                    EditText mainText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.maintext);
                    mainText.setText(text);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Then register the receiver in the onResume() method of the MainActivity:

```
registerReceiver(textReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_UPDATE_TEXT));
```

Don't forget to unregister it in the onPause() method:

```
unregisterReceiver(textReceiver);
```

**Next**, in each of your Activities (Regular and Things) button onclick handler, send the broadcast like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your other code

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.ACTION_UPDATE_TEXT);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Comment: I have not tried your code yet, but I feel it will work as I have experienced some message handlers, As bounty is expiring today ill award the bounty to you.Anyway I'll test it and let you know.
Thanks for the Help

Comment: Thank you so much. I am pretty sure it will work as i employ this technique to share data between asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass the edit text instance, mainText, into your Regular activity, and just update that?

Hit me up if you're confused.

**Update**
Try this, tell me if it works:

in your `MainActivity` ,

```
int id = mainText.getId();

intent.putExtra("tv", id );
```

and In your `Regular` activity.

```
//in onCreate
int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("tv");

EditText mainText=(EditText) findViewById(id);
```

This is untested code, try and see if it works. Hit me up with results!

Comment: Yah a bit confused, but i thing i got what you are trying to say, but if you can brief it a little it would be great.

Comment: I will supply a solution shortly

Comment: Hey Buddy Its great, I think your solution will work, but unfortunately I can't share the bounty between 2. So I am awarding it to @appsroxcom as he has some more codes that will be clear to all which is similar to you.
Also I think we need to create a broadcast receiver or a Message Handler, instead of getting the value inside oncreate as it is gona happen only once.
I have not tried yours yet but ill try and let you know soon, I have to award the bounty today that's why this haste.
Thanks for your help
I have marked yours as useful

Answer (score 0):

In your Tab Host java file, 
Insert this following code.

```
View MainActivityView=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
EditText et=(EditText)MainActivityView.findViewById(R.id.maintext);
```

You are getting a null pointer exception because edittext box is not in your tab host view..

Comment: Tried this now...! 
but no luck again I got a null pointer exception again.
It says it cant start the activity that has to open inside the tab.
"03-24 21:27:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(13386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 21:27:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(13386): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.batz.voiceforyou/com.batz.voiceforyou.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.batz.voiceforyou/com.batz.voiceforyou.Regular}:"

Comment: Instead of tab hosts why dont you try fragments ??? 
There are compatabilities packages like android.support,v4.app.fragment etc etc

Comment: Tabs and Activities just dont go together..
Try Actionbarsherlock and ViewPagerIndicator It will solve your problems...

Comment: Ok I'll look into fragments soon as i go home.Thanks for the quick response.